# Как скомандовать ОС открыть графический файл из C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Не могу открыть графический файл. Сначала пробовал это:

```
#define FNAME "D:/Scream297and396.jpg"              
...            
int main() { char fname [50] =FNAME;        
FILE *fout;            
fout = fopen(FNAME,"r");           
return 0; }
```

...но при запуске этой программы ничего не происходит, файл не открывается. Точнее, видимо, он всё же открывается, но для считывания самих данных файла этой же программой.

Мне же необходимо открыть файл не **для программы**, а **для пользователя**, способом по умолчанию в операционной системе. В данном случае файл `D:/Scream297and396.jpg` должен открыться в просмотрщике картинок, установленном для `*.jpg`.

Как это сделать?

Comment: Первое что бросается в глаза - неправильный слэш в пути к файлу. И не забудьте про экранирование.

Comment: А что означает «не получается»? В вашем коде всё выглядит нормально.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов: Насколько мне помнится, рантайм Visual Studio принимает что прямые, что обратные слеши.

Comment: @Данил: И чем, по-вашему, открытие jpeg отличается от открытия exe? Что для вас означает слово «открыть»?

Comment: @VladD: vs2012 выдает  error C4996: 'fopen': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using fopen_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. Если компилировать с этой ошибкой, то просто открывается консоль и ничего не происходит.

Comment: @Данил: Ну да, всё правильно. А что, по вашему мнению, должно произойти?

Comment: @VladD: как тогда сделать, чтобы файл открылся?

Comment: @Данил: Что значит, по-вашему, «файл открылся»?

Comment: @VladD: также открылся, как открываются файлы в ОС...не пойму к чему вы клоните

Comment: К тому, что вы открыли файл для считывания данных в вашу программу, и ничего видимого не произошло. А нужно вам отдать команду оболочке ОС открыть этот файл способом по умолчанию.

Comment: @D-side: не подскажите, что за команда тогда мне нужна?

Comment: Я исправил вопрос (правка на проверке) и предложил переоткрытие.

Comment: @D-side: спасибо, исправил

Comment: @Nofate наверняка. А теперь, когда оставлять ответы снова можно...

Comment: @Nofate: большое спасибо!

Answer (score 8):

Полагаю, вам нужно что-то вроде этого:

```
ShellExecute(handle, "open", "D:\\Scream297and396.jpg", nullptr, nullptr, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

Подробнее о возможностях `ShellExecute` читайте на [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/bb762153(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле это очень просто:

```
system("start graph.png");
```